# I did everything, but again giving the latitude and longitude of 0.0

Tags: android, mobile, location

Class for getting Location

```
public class TrackGPS extends Service implements LocationListener {



private final Context mContext;


boolean checkGPS = false;


boolean checkNetwork = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location loc;
double latitude;
double longitude;


private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;


private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public TrackGPS(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    getLocation();
}

private Location getLocation() {

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        checkGPS = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        checkNetwork = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!checkGPS && !checkNetwork) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Service Provider Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (checkNetwork) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        loc = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    }

                    if (loc != null) {
                        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
                catch(SecurityException e){

                }
            }
        }
        // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
        if (checkGPS) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"GPS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (loc == null) {
                try {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        loc = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (loc != null) {
                            latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                            longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SecurityException e) {

                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return loc;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if (loc != null) {
        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
    }
    return longitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    if (loc != null) {
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
    }
    return latitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);


    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Not Enabled");

    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you wants to turn On GPS");


    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


    alertDialog.show();
}


public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {

        locationManager.removeUpdates(TrackGPS.this);
    }
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle  ) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

 }
}
```

---

Code for Main Activity  is

```
 private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 1;
 String mPermission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

private Button b_get;
private TrackGPS gps;
double longitude;
double latitude;
//----------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    b_get = (Button)findViewById(R.id.locationBtn);




    b_get.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            gps = new TrackGPS(MainActivity.this);


            if(gps.canGetLocation()){


                longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                latitude = gps .getLatitude();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Longitude:"+Double.toString(longitude)+"\nLatitude:"+Double.toString(latitude),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {

                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
    });

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= 23) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(mPermission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{mPermission,
                    },
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
            return ;
        }

        else
        {


        }
    }





protected void onDestroy() { super.onDestroy()  gps.stopUsingGPS();
    }
```

Comment: Help emergency @peter

Comment: *I did everything* no, you didn't ... you are only depending on terrible androidhive's so called tutorial ... **getLastKnownLocation may returns null** so you have to wait until (asynchrounous call) onLocationChanged is called and get location there

Comment: I dont know @Selvin

Comment: Would you explain more clearly @Selvin

Comment: @PravinSuthar  help me

Comment: Beginner on Android @Selvin

Comment: Please check inside app info,permission really allowed and also r u adding permission inside manifest file?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: this manifest file @PravinSuthar

Answer (score 1):

Add Required permissions in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Which android OS version do you have?